# load image to a cube three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

Hi I trying to load a image to a cube but i don't know what is wrong. The cube is fine but not the image.
Here is the link: http://diegoddox.bitbucket.org/loadimage/

```
var scene, camera, renderer;
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setClearColorHex(0xeeeeee);
renderer.clear();
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
scene = new THREE.Scene();
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 5000 );
camera.position.z = 800;
camera.lookAt(scene.position);
scene.add(camera);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("img.jpg")
});
material.map.needsUpdate = true; 
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(300, 300, 300), material);
cube.overdraw = true;
cube.position.x = 0;
cube.rotation.x = -20;
cube.rotation.z = -2;
scene.add(cube);
renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

Comment: Are you running locally from file system? Or using a web server? Can you check if "img.jpg" is loaded in dev tools or firebug etc.?

Comment: Yes I'm running locally. And when i dibug i get this error.

WebGL: INVALID_VALUE: texImage2D: invalid image localhost:1
WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: generateMipmap: level 0 not power of 2 or not all the same size localhost:1
WebGL: drawElements: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering or is not 'texture complete'

Comment: Have a look at this - https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/How-to-run-things-locally

Comment: Id suggest downloading xampp or similar very easy to run local server

Comment: I will try on the server. Thanks @Neil

Comment: Looking at your error, you also need image that is power of 2, so that is 256x256, 512x512 or 1024x1024 dimensions etc.

Comment: Well still not work here is the link. http://diegoddox.bitbucket.org/loadimage/

Comment: The image size is 800x450

Comment: Ok try it at 512x512 to see if it works

Comment: I have resize the image but stil nor working

Comment: Here is the image 512x512 and still not working :http://diegoddox.bitbucket.org/loadimage/img.jpg

Comment: have a look in resources tab in chrome dev tools and confirm img is actually loading?

Comment: Yes the image is loading but not showing.

Comment: final guess, try a png

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The image loading is asynchronous.

What is happening is that your single `render()` call is occurring before the image finishes loading.

Enter

```
renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

into the Console, and you will see that the texture renders.

You need to add a callback to your `loadTexture()` function and call `render()` from there, or, alternatively, you can add an animation loop using `requestAnimationFrame()`.

Comment: I call the render when the window is loaded ;) and it works. Thanks a lot @WestLangley

Comment: How do you call the render when the window is loaded?