# three.js texture is not loading

Tags: three.js, textures

by trying a tutorial ( http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2013/09/16/how-to-make-the-earth-in-webgl/ ) the needed texture is not loading. 
Here is my trying code in the index.html script area

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/threejs/build/three.js"></script>
<script>
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth /     window.innerHeight, 0.01, 1000 );
    camera.position.z = 1.5; 
    var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('images/earthmap1k.jpg');
    texture.anisotropy = 16;
    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { map: texture } );

    /*material.bumpMap = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('images/earthbump1k.jpg');
    material.bumpScale = 0.05;*/
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x888888);
    scene.add(light);
    var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xCCCCCC, 1 );
    light.position.set(5,3,5);
    scene.add(light); 

    var earthMesh = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.5, 32, 32), material);
    scene.add(earthMesh);

    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    var $container = $('#container');
    $container.append(renderer.domElement);

    renderer.render(scene, camera);

</script>
```

so what I'm doing wrong here???

thanks for your help in advance

best regards 
Karsten

Comment: Do you have the image file in <CURRENT DIR>/images/earthmap1k.jpg ? Also check the Javascript console logs in your browser (ctrl+shift+k in Firefox, ctrl+shift+j in Chrome)

Comment: hi prabindh, yes it is in this directory. In Console Log the image is shown correctly.

Comment: check your texture image size, then check geometry radius also..

Comment: Hi, after alerting texture.image hat is a HTMLImageObject the texture is shown. If I remove the alert method the texture is away too. What is that for an effect???

Comment: It seems the image isn't fully loaded by adding it to the Mesh. Is that possible?

Comment: Size of Image is shown with 500 in height and 1000 in width

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14959276/load-image-to-a-cube-three-js/14964016#14964016

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
var tUrl = "images/earthbump1k.jpg";
var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(tUrl, {}, createMesh);
function createMesh(texture){
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { map: texture } );
var earthMesh = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.5, 32, 32), material);
scene.add(earthMesh);
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work too. The same feature. If I'm alerting something one time then the earth is shown but without alerting all is black.

Comment: here the creeteMesh() is onload function...once your texture loaded the onload fuunction is called by callback... can you share your full code..

Comment: so now i fixed it by using a function named animate and doing requestAnimationFrame, then it works without the alerts :)

Comment: Code is too long for comments and i can write an answer to my question first in 8h.