# ThreeJS, 3D object texture not working only online

Tags: json, 3d, three.js, textures, maya

I'm using three.js for an AR application to show a 3D object (exported from Maya with maya exporter to threejs) on a marker detected using JSARToolKit.

**It all works fine on localhost**(I see texture), but when I upload it online (github) and I see the preview object appears all black without texture (like if I remove the light).

```
// load the model
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader;
var object;
//var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
loader.load('js/object3d.js', function(geometry, materials){
var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials);
object = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

container.add(object);
});

var ambLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x909090, 2.0 );
container.add( ambLight );
```

Any ideas?

Comment: in chrome press f12 and check for errors in Console section. if there is none then switch to Network tab and reload your game to see which assets are loading and which are not.

Comment: No errors in console. Everything's loading.

Comment: @Vig Can you post a link to your demo?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this is the problem, but it might be that your loader runs into some error but since you didn't set an error handler for your loader you don't get notified.

The `JSONLoader` load method takes four arguments (`url`, `onLoad`, `onProgress`, `onError`) as you can see [here in the class on line 40](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/loaders/JSONLoader.js#L40).

Try to set an error handler (`onError` callback method) and see what you get. For example:

```
var onload = function(geometry, materials){
    var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials);
    object = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    container.add(object);
});
var onProgress = function(){
    // your optional on progress logic
}
var onError = function(error){
    console.log( error );
}

var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader;
loader.load('js/object3d.js', onLoad, onProgress, onError);
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion!  
Actually I got this error in console:  

`htmlpreview.github.io/:1 [.CommandBufferContext]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glGenerateMipmap: Can not generate mips`  
________________________________________________
`(255)htmlpreview.github.io/:1 [.CommandBufferContext]RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering.`  
________________________________________________
`htmlpreview.github.io/:1 WebGL: too many errors, no more errors will be reported to the console for this context.`

Comment: @Vig the error message gives some hints on what might be causing the problem. Is your texture size power of 2 (so, for example 64x64, 128x128, 256x256, etc).

Comment: Yes, it wasn't power-of-2, but now I fix it, re-exported object from maya, but I still get the same errors in console.

Comment: Read [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/3574): You get this error probably because *"the texture is being used before being loaded. Aka you should be waiting for the loadTexture callback before using the texture?"*

Comment: @Vig Check also [this answer from WestLangley](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14964016/1697459)

Comment: Why does it work on localhost? The texture is loaded in Sources tab con chrome console.
I'm wondering if this could be a "github issue" but to access webcam I need https and I didn't find anything free.

Comment: @Vig I don't know, can think of several reasons. You should try to debug and find out. Might be that it loads so fast on localhost that the image is loaded before the first render call. In that case it works as expected. You could simulate a slow connection on your localhost in chrome. Check [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToSimulateALowBandwidthConnectionForTestingWebSitesAndApplications.aspx) on how to do it. You should empty your cache because if the image is still in cache it will also load fast.